# How do I solve this load error problem in irb?

Tags: ruby, irb

I can't understand why this error occurs. I have a file named `hello.rb`, it is in `"C/Ruby192/bin/hello.rb"`.

```
irb(main):005:0>load("hello.rb")  
Load Error: no such file to load -- hello.rb  
    from(irb):5:in`load'  
    from(irb):5  
    from C:/Ruby192/bin/irb:12:in`<main>'
```

I would be very appreciative if you could solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

From the [fine manual](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001417):

> **load(filename, wrap=false) → true**
>   Loads and executes the Ruby program in the file *filename*. If the *filename* does not resolve to an absolute path, the file is searched for in the library directories listed in `$:`.

Your `"hello.rb"` is not an absolute path so `load` looks through `$:` to find it in the library directories. Presumably, `'C/Ruby192/bin'` isn't in `$:` (or `'.'` isn't in `$:` if you're in `C/Ruby192/bin/` already). Try specifying the full path:

```
> load('C/Ruby192/bin/hello.rb')
> load('./hello.rb') # If you're in C/Ruby192/bin/ already
```